# Is my approach valid for showing that my algorithm (usage of python's random.sample) is NOT susceptible to the Birthday Problem?

Tags: python, random, scipy-optimize, birthday-paradox

I tried to prove to myself one way or the other whether the way I was generating these "codes" was susceptible to the Birthday Problem, in which case--I tell myself--collisions should eventually grow with the square of the number of reserved codes, with a large enough number of reserved codes.

I believe the approximated formula I am recalling was `collision_probability = k**2 / 2n`, where `k` is the number of items (or codes which will be reserved) and `n` is the number of buckets (or possible codes).

Below, I go on to calculate P(collision) for each level of reserved codes, 0 - 1 million. Then I fit the probabilities at each point to a line of best fit. --- **My most important question is, did I assume what was I trying to prove somewhere along the way here?** Or otherwise, miss the point of the birthday problem's effect on the probability of putting K items into N buckets?

```py
    import itertools
    import sys
    import csv
    import random
    import string
    from functools import partial
    
    
    def calculate_num_collisions(gen_code, iterations, codes=None):
        num_collisions = 0
        for _ in range(iterations):
            code = gen_code()
            if code in codes:
                num_collisions += 1
    
        # Round to 4 digits, for probability visibility down to e.g. 0.0001,
        # or 0.01% probability, in other words, really 2 digits
        return round(num_collisions / iterations, 4)
    
    
    def generate_code(possible_values, length):
        # Try to use the exact same algorithm as in my codebase, another place
        return "".join(random.sample(possible_values, length))
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    
        if len(sys.argv) < 2:
            print("Please supply output file.")
            sys.exit(1)
    
        possible_values = string.digits
        length = 6
        iterations_to_check = 40
        # iterations is how many samples to take at each level of codes already assigned. 
    
        _gen_code = partial(generate_code, possible_values, length)
    
        with open(sys.argv[1], "w") as csvfile:
    
            codes = set()
            total_buckets = len(possible_values) ** length
            fieldnames = ["current_buckets", "observed_collision_probability"]
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
    
            # rather than generate codes randomly in this outer loop, create a generator
            # that will produce all possible such codes -- wastes less time
            all_possibilities = itertools.product(possible_values, repeat=length)
            for i in range(total_buckets):
    
                observed_collision_probability = calculate_num_collisions(
                    gen_code=_gen_code, iterations=iterations_to_check, codes=codes
                )
                current_buckets = total_buckets - len(codes)
                writer.writerow(
                    dict(
                        observed_collision_probability=observed_collision_probability,
                        current_buckets=current_buckets,
                    )
                )
                try:
                    codes.add("".join(next(all_possibilities)))
                except StopIteration:
                    break
```

So, when I take the data generated from this script, and plot it along with a fitted linear equation...

[image: usage of curve_fit]

I get the following:

[image: data fitted to a linear model]

The point is, it looks very linear.

... Choosing a quadratic objective function instead results in a coefficient of 0 on the quadratic component. (Smaller questions might include whether I used the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` function correctly here, as I am new to usage of data science python libraries.)

Thanks in advance, sorry for openness of question.

I referred to these questions, but I'm still confused:

- [What is the probability of collision with a 6 digit random alphanumeric code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591117/what-is-the-probability-of-collision-with-a-6-digit-random-alphanumeric-code)
- [random.choice not random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366047/random-choice-not-random)
- [Random is barely random at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145510/random-is-barely-random-at-all)
- [What is the difference between random.sample and random.shuffle in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798363/what-is-the-difference-between-random-sample-and-random-shuffle-in-python)

Comment: The approximation `p_collision(k, n) = k**2 / 2n` is only good for probabilities ≤ 1/2, which is equivalent to `k ≤ sqrt(n)`. Using the Poisson approximation for the probability of collision, you find that by the time `k ≥ 3sqrt(n)` the probability exceeds 0.99. In other words, for a pool size of 1E6 and a sample of 3000 outcomes from that pool, there's less than 1 in 100 chance of not getting any duplicates.